# Ransack association scopes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations, ransack

I am trying to use a scope from an association in a ransack filter; a `Contact` has_many `Surveys` through `Subscriptions`.  I created the Survey scope below:

```
scope :score_in, -> (nps_type = nil) do
  where(score: NPS_RANGE[nps_type])
end

NPS_RANGE = {
   nil        => [*0..10],
  'detractor' => [*0..6],
  'passive'   => [7, 8],
  'promoter'  => [9, 10]
}
```

Yet when I do `Contact.ransack(surveys_score_in: 'detractor')` it doesn't work and looks up based on `0` since `'string'.to_i == 0` instead of `[*0..6]`.

I even defined `self.ransackable_scopes` to whitelist it as well but it still wasn't running. Any ideas on how to get Ransack to use this scope?

Comment: I think, you have tested it in your console to test if it is working or not.. Right?

Comment: Yes but it looks it up based on `0` since it converts the `'detractor'.to_i`. Here is the SQL generated:
 `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT "subscriptions"."id") FROM "subscriptions" LEFT OUTER JOIN "surveys" ON "surveys"."subscription_id" =  "subscriptions"."id" WHERE "surveys"."score" IN (0)`